# Simpler way to write the scramble function

Tags: javascript

I want a simpler way for the function `scramble(str1,str2)` so that if a portion of `str1` can be arranged to match `str2` . Note that all the letters to be used are lowercase . I used the following code and it worked , but can anyone show me a simpler way .

```
function scramble(str1,str2){
     str2 = str2.split('');
     str1 = str1.split('');
     let arr = [] , condition ;
     arr.length = str2.length;

     for(let i =0;i<str2.length;i++){
      for(let a= 0 ;a<str1.length;a++){
       if(str2[i] == str1[a]){
        str1[a] = '';
        arr[i] = 'true'
         break;
       }
      }
     }
      for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
       if(arr[i] == undefined){
        return false
       }
      }
      return true
    }
  console.log(scramble('rkqodlw','world')) //true;
  console.log(scramble('cedewaraaossoqqyt','codewars'))//true
  console.log(scramble('katas','steak')) //false
  console.log(scramble('scriptjava','javascript'))//true
  console.log(scramble('scriptingjava','javascript'))//true
  console.log(scramble('scriptsjava','javascripts')//true
  console.log(scramble('jscripts','javascript')) //false
  console.log(scramble('aabbcamaomsccdd','commas')) //true
```

Comment: Some examples of input/output would help.

Comment: You may want the code review stack exchange.

Comment: I just did , sorry forgot about the examples thanks for reminding me .

Comment: Wait ... if this is a codewars kata, solve it and you see the solution of others ...

Comment: yes it is but it is taking too much time to execute... All tests are passed but i need a simpler code .

Comment: you dont understand codewars.

Comment: perhaps , If i am missing something can you enlighten me ?? I would be thankful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make count all chars in `str1`, then go over `str2`, decrement the count and return false if it reaches 0:

```
 const count = {};

 for(const char of str1)
   count[char] = (count[char] || 0) + 1;

for(const char of str2)
  if(!count[char]--) return false;

return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a version of generic issue of checking if one set of elements is a subset of another.

The base step to solve this task is to take first element of `set1` and check if it is present in `set2`. If it isn't we return `false`. If it is we check the next element with `set2` minus the matched element;
The base case is when we have an empty set (because empty set is a subset of any set)

```
function check(str1, str2) {
  if (str2.length === 0) {
     return true;
  }
  const [first, ...rest] = str1;
  const idx = str2.indexOf(first);
  if (idx !== -1) {
    const str2Rest = [...str2.slice(0, idx), ...str2.slice(idx+1)];
    return check(rest, str2Rest);
  }
  return true;
}
```

You can also first sort the strings and then go through both knowing that the matched char might be only on the current position or at the higher index

```
function sorted(str1, str2) {
  str1 = [...str1].sort();
  str2 = [...str2].sort();
  let s1 = 0;
  let s2 = 0;
  while (s1 < str1.length && s2 < str2.length) {
    if(str1[s1] === str2[s2]) {
      s1 += 1;
    }
    s2 += 1;
  }
  return s1 === str1.length
}
```

The most performant solution for unsorted items is to go through the chars of both in the worst case only one:

```
function performant(str1, str2) {
  const stash = {};
  let s1 = 0;
  let s2 = 0;
  while (s1 < str1.length && s2 < str2.length) {
    const ch1 = str[s1];
    const ch2 = str[s2];
    if(ch1 === ch2) {
      s1 += 1;  
      s2 += 1; 
      continue;   
    }
    if (stash[ch1]) {
      s1 += 1; 
      stash[ch1] -= 1;
    }
    stash[ch2] = (stash[ch2] | 0) + 1;
    s2 += 1;
  }
  return s1 === str1.length;
}
```